# Texture mapping option disappear in Blender 2.72

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, particles

I want to make explosion pieces fade out when particles reach their life limits, just as this video does: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gD8qlNdEt6E. In the video, begin at 18:55, the video maker creates a new material texture and set its mapping coordinates to "UV", I can see the option "Mapping" from the video:

[image: screen shot form video]

Yet, somehow when I try to do it in Blender 2.72, I just cannot find such an option, here is the picture I took from my Blender:

[image: my texture options in blender]

You can see there is just no mapping option at all. So could anyone please tell me how to solve this problem?

By the way, you may want to know the Material.001 is created in cycles engine, because I really need to blend this effect with some other cycles-created stuffs to make an animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cycles you can fade out particles by using the particle age and lifetime to control the mix of transparency.

[image]

By dividing the age by the lifetime you get a value that goes from 1.0 to 0.0 over the lifetime of the particle, then connect that to a ColorRamp and you can clearly control what part of the lifetime the particle fades out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you are using The internal render in the first image , the second image is in cycles render.

[image]

[image]

Im not sure if it is possible to use this in cycles , You may have to use nodes.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, I just found that if I create material in internal render engine, I have this choice, yet the UV map does not work when I switched into Cycles, by the way do you know how to make explosion fade in cycles?

Comment: Thanks for the thumbs up :)

No sorry , i don't use cycles render

Comment: @Xiangyu.Guo In cycles you use the *particle age* output of the *particle info* node, as sambler nicely explains in his answer.